# Writing/Adding new options to iPhone's .plist

Tags: ios, iphone, plist, jailbreak

I want to add a new option to one of my iPhone's .plist files. I can do it in iPhone's settings page, by creating a new plist, but if I want to get new functions in, for example, Wifi settings (a new on/off switch), I can't seem to do it. Found some plist files named `com.apple.wifi` etc. but they were in another format. I converted them to xml, but I didn't find the plist which contains information about these on/off switches, just the plist for connections.

Where can I find the plist, which contains the settings GUI elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the WiFi settings bundle at:

```
/System/Library/PreferenceBundles/AirPortSettings.bundle
```

And the root **plist** file that Setings app load from is at:

```
/Applications/Preferences.app/Settings.plist
```